# I have 2 salesforce org and I am making api call from one org's lwc component to get access token of another org but I am getting below error

Tags: lightning-web-components, rest-api, cors

This is my JS code from LWC component.

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
const MY_URL = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token';
const Data ='username=username.com&password=password&grant_type=password&client_id=3MVG9wt4IL4O5wvLJqYlIli4gRIGD1RyFRZnciIpY8pOnE.mDEfg8Hf.WMZM5X7JR83hX1F0i4OSwffdADfQZ&client_secret=8B8F9EA2796C23B499D6979A0EF4C97A8AF53F2C5791CE7734355317B2DBDB1DF01';
export default class GithubInfo extends LightningElement {
    user = {};
    myid;
    
    updateid(event){
        this.myid=event.target.value;
    }
    getGithubStats() {
        if(true) {
            this.user = {};
            fetch(MY_URL, {
                method:'POST',
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                },
                body:Data
              })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                if(response.ok) {
                    return response.json();
                } else {
                    throw Error(response);
                }
            })
            .then(Userdata => {
                this.user = {
                    token: Userdata.access_token,
                    URL: Userdata.instance_url
                };
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
        }
    }

}
```

I am getting error in browser console as "access to fetch at 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token' from origin 'https://companycom-6b-dev-ed.lightning.force.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
aura_prod.js:80
POST https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)".

I have included the url of org from I am makig api call in another orgs CORS. And even mentioned the 'https://login.salesforce.com' in trusted site and remote site setting.

Answer (score 0):

The **CORS** error you're encountering is a common issue when making **API** calls from a web browser to a domain that is different from the one serving the web page. This is due to the browser's same-origin policy, which restricts web pages from requesting a domain other than the one that served the web page unless the server provides an explicit allowance using **CORS** headers.

Here are some steps you can take to resolve this issue:

1. **Check CORS Settings:** Ensure that the Salesforce org you're making the API call to has the calling org's domain in its **CORS** allowlist. This is done in the Salesforce setup under **Security** > **CORS**.
2. **Use Named Credentials:** Instead of making a direct API call from the LWC, consider using **Named Credentials** in Salesforce. This allows you to authenticate and make callouts to external services securely without exposing sensitive information in your JavaScript code.
3. **Apex Callout:** Make the API call from an Apex class instead of directly from the LWC. Apex is not subject to the same-origin policy, so it can make callouts to other domains. You can then expose the Apex method to your LWC using the `@AuraEnabled` annotation.

For more detail, you can refer to Salesforce documentation on [CORS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/extend_code_cors.htm) and [Calling APIs from LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2022/03/working-with-cors-and-csp-to-call-apis-from-lwc).

Comment: Actually I been able to do that from apex I just wanted to try using LWC.